# Upload file to website and display it without refreshing site ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: javascript, html, file, asp.net-core

I am trying to upload a file to my website and preview it without making the website refresh, but I cannot figure out how to do it, right now I select a file with the `<input type=file>` but I have a JQuery script that onchange submits the input with this code:

```
document.getElementById('file-upload').onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("upload-form").submit();
};
```

How can I make this without refreshing the page after the POST?
My Form looks like this (It is an ASP.NET Core 6 project):

```
<form id="upload-form" asp-action="UploadFile" asp-controller="Home" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Ladda upp
                </label>
                <input id="file-upload" type="file" name="stlFile" />
            </form>
```

Comment: You need to make ajax call to do that.

Comment: An Iframe might be worth considering/trying.

Comment: This might be more complicated than I thought, sins I use ASP.NET Core MVC this might not be possible... in an easy way to say the least

Comment: Do you want to display the file directly without refreshing it after uploading it?

Comment: Yes, but I dont know if thats possible..

Comment: What type are you uploading? It's easy to do if it's a picture.

Comment: It is an .stl file, to preview 3d models